# Use 'class' (or other reserved keyword) as property on anonymous type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper, anonymous-types

Ok, I cant find the answer to this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Action", null, new {class="myClass"})%>
```

I want to set the CSS class attribute of the generated  element.

Obviously, C# will not allow me to use "class" as the name of an object's member.

What should I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can You try with escaping the class with : @.

So, please modify your code to :

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Action", null, new {@class="myClass"})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a capital 'C' in Class also works, from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10912683/192221). The attribute names are converted to lower case.

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Action", null, new { Class = "myClass" })%>
```